# Routing to different controllers depending on authentication

Tags: php, symfony, security, routes

In rewriting an app using Symfony2, I'm attempting to preserve some legacy behaviour and am looking for a clean solution.

My goal is to have the URI "/" display a splash page if the user is not logged in, and the same URI display a per-user dashboard if they are logged in.

The solution also needs to be scalable - there are several pages on the "public" site which have different representations on the "private" site (i.e. the index, support, about, contact, etc) - because of this I can't simply use a catch-all route and forward to the correct controller myself.

I have one potential solution, which I will post as an answer, but I'm looking for advice on better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

N.B. This answer is something of a hack; I'm posting it in the hopes of finding a better way.

One way to achieve this could be to make use of the Routing system's support for [conditions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/conditions.html) - this has the advantage of not affecting URL generation and allowing the routing system to take care of parameters, etc.

However, in order to use the condition for this purpose, we need to expose the request's authentication status through either the Request or the RequestContext (the only two available variables).

This can be done by creating an EventListener which runs before the RouterListener and stores the authentication status in the Request's attributes.

Unfortunately, as shown in the [event reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html), the firewall only runs after the RouterListener, meaning that the authentication status isn't available in our listener.

As far as I can tell, the only solution is to modify the priorities such that the Firewall runs first, then our new EventListener, then finally the RouterListener. This is almost definitely a bad idea, and could cause unexpected effects.

I welcome any better suggestions as to how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on symfony3, but here's my approach. After login, I send all users to /login/redirect, with the controller shown below. It's simple and uses the built-in ROLES_* functionality.

```
/**
 * Redirect users after login based on various checks
 *
 * @Route("/login/redirect", name="_login_redirect")
 */
public function loginRedirectAction()
{
    // Send user to admin page or order page based on credentials
    if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_SUPERUSER')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_home');
    } elseif ($this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('dashboard');
    } else {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('order_page');
    }
}
```

To handle those not logged in, I use some simple logic in my twig template. Note that symfony automatically gives all logged in users a ROLES_USER role.

```
    {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
        {# User is logged in, do something appropriate #}
        <li>{{ app.user ? app.user.name : '' }}</li>&nbsp;
        {# Useful stuff #}
    {% else %}
        {# Show login link, or give other info #}
        <li><a href="{{ path('security_login') }}">Login</a></li>
    {% endif %}
```